# Flutter: How to size progress indicator inside the container?

Tags: flutter

```
Container(
  height: 150,
  width: 150,
  child: _loading
      ? Container(
          height: 50,
          width: 50,
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        )
      : ElevatedButton(
          style: ButtonStyle(
              backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.blue)),
          onPressed: () {},
          child: Text('update'),
        ),
);
```

I am trying to switch button to the `CircularProgressIndicator()` like the above code. However, the indicator's size does not set to the parent's container size (width height 50), but it is set to the grandpa `Container (width height 150)`. Is there any way that I can set the size to 50 px container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the `CircularProgressIndicator` in a `FittedBox`

Like so:

```
Container(
  height: 50,
  width: 50,
  child: FittedBox(child:  CircularProgressIndicator()),
)
```

Comment: Please accept if it works for you.

Comment: I was waiting for the 15 mins mark!